# Why don't iostream objects overload operator bool?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, iostream

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331292/c-rely-on-implicit-conversion-to-bool-in-conditions/1331475#1331475) I talk about using a `std::ifstream` object's conversion to `bool` to test whether the stream is still in a good state.  I looked in the Josuttis book for more information (p. 600 if you're interested), and it turns out that the `iostream` objects actually overload `operator void*`.  It returns a null pointer when the stream is bad (which can be implicitly converted to `false`), and a non-null pointer otherwise (implicitly converted to `true`).  Why don't they just overload `operator bool`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an instance of the "safe bool" problem.

Here is a good article: http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html .

C++0x helps the situation with `explicit` conversion functions, as well as the change that Kristo mentions. See also [Is the safe-bool idiom obsolete in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242768/is-the-safe-bool-idiom-obsolete) .

Answer (score 13):

It looks like the C++0x standard section 27.4.4.3 has the answer (emphasis mine).

```
operator unspecified-bool-type() const;
```

> Returns: If `fail()` then a value that
>   will evaluate false in a boolean
>   context; otherwise a value that will
>   evaluate true in a boolean context.
>   **The value type returned shall not be
>   convertible to `int`.**
>
> Note: This conversion can be used in
>   contexts where a `bool` is expected
>   (e.g., an if condition); however,
>   implicit conversions (e.g., to `int`)
>   that can occur with `bool` are not
>   allowed, eliminating some sources of
>   user error.

Comment: This answer is obsolete. It wasn't standardized because explicit conversion functions were added.

Answer (score 0):

The newest C++11 requires that:

```
explicit operator bool() const;
```

See C++11 27.5.5.4-1. The 'explicit' seems odd to me, though.

Comment: `explicit` is the reason it was added. An `explicit` conversion function such as this will only apply if it is the *only* conversion, in this case it will convert `iostream` to `bool` but not to `int` via an intermediate `bool` conversion. Read the other answers on this page to learn about the Safe Bool Idiom.