# fstream unix problem in reading

Tags: c++, unix, fstream

I am trying to read from binary file on UNIX. The file exists and has several data information in it.

The code looks like this:

```
fstrean fstrHandler;

string strFileName;

char Buf[30000];

fstrHandler.open(strFileName.c_str(), ios::in | ios::binary);

fstrHandler.seekp(0, std::ios_base::beg);

std::cout<< "Posi before read= "<< fstrHandler.tellg()<<endl; //*** Show after running 0

fstrHandler.read (Buf, 400);

std::cout<< "Posi after read= "<< fstrHandler.tellg()<<endl; //*** Show after running 0

std::cout<< " gcount ()= "<< fstrHandler.gcount ()<< << endl; //*** Show after running 0

if (fstrHandler.eof ()) {
       fstrHandler.clear();
}
```

After the read I get that the position in file is still zero zero, but the file is not empty.

Comment: s/fstrean/fstream/. Besides that, you should check if `fstream::open` really succeeded, e.g.: `assert(fstrHandler.good())`.

Comment: I didn't add it but it exists

Comment: And following the below comments, assert(fstrHandler) instead of good().

Answer (score 2):

Try `seekg` rather than `seekp`, and is there 400 bytes in the file? this appears to work okay for me, if you input a file that contains more than 400 bytes. If less, then the `tellg` after read reports -1, but `gcount()` is correct.

Also, after opening the file - test to see if the file was indeed opened e.g.

```
if (fstrHandler)
{
// do stuff
}
else
  std::cerr << "foo bar" << std::endl;
```

Comment: That condition will always evaluate true. There's an `operator!` for that though, or `good()`, or `fail()`, or `is_open()`.

Comment: @jweyrich: if (stream) isn't always true [after opening](http://codepad.org/ARjqICEB), and it's the opposite of op!, which is itself the same as fail().  Don't use good().

Comment: @Fred Nurk: there's an `operator bool()`? I always thought the `operator!` would require it to be explicitly used. Seems I've been wrong ever since. Why not use good()? It checks bad/eof/fail, which seems okay in this case too.

Comment: @Fred Nurk: Oh nevermind, I found the answer to my 1st question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334858/why-dont-iostream-objects-overload-operator-bool). Nice catch :-)

Comment: @jweyrich: Good() tests all three, but eof() being true does not imply fail() (which actually checks failbit and badbit) is true.

Comment: @Fred Nurk: sure. But it's okay to use it in the presented scenario, unless OP wants to distinguish the cause, which doesn't seem to be the case as he didn't have any condition.

Comment: @jweyrich: It is sometimes equivalent.  The problem is the sometimes.  If you never use good(), you never have a problem remembering when it is equivalent and when it isn't.  It is very, *very* rare to want to know eofbit might be set but fail() is false; thus good() should very, *very* rarely be used.